# Using ffmpeg to split video files by size and by name and by name

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing

I’m trying to split a video by size but I don’t know which code I have to use. And I want it listing output mp4 files as sorting for example name: Video 1 - Part(2).mp4, Video 2 - Part(2).mp4, Video 3 - Part(2).mp4 (You can think sorting name is incorrect but I want to part name locate should be after the “Video” sentence)

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Hello, new contributor, your question is not very clear. If you are looking for ffmpeg command to split the video, the answers are already available, e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1670/how-can-i-use-ffmpeg-to-split-mpeg-video-into-10-minute-chunks. If you are looking for some help with your program, please provide example code.

Comment: maybe ask on superuser